# Problem installing a modified rpm

Tags: centos, rpm

I modified the rpm package and it worked but when I tried to install it via rpm I encountered this problem

```
[root@vps8865 ~]# cd rpmbuild/
[root@vps8865 rpmbuild]# cd RPMS/
[root@vps8865 RPMS]# ls
x86_64
[root@vps8865 RPMS]# cd x86_64/
[root@vps8865 x86_64]# ls
libblkid-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm        libmount-devel-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm      libuuid-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm        util-linux-debuginfo-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm
libblkid-devel-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm  libsmartcols-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm        libuuid-devel-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm  uuidd-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm
libmount-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm        libsmartcols-devel-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm  util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm
[root@vps8865 x86_64]# rpm -i util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libblkid = 2.23.2-65.el7.1 is needed by util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64
        libmount = 2.23.2-65.el7.1 is needed by util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64
        libsmartcols = 2.23.2-65.el7.1 is needed by util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64
        libuuid = 2.23.2-65.el7.1 is needed by util-linux-2.23.2-65.el7.1.x86_64
[root@vps8865 x86_64]#
[root@vps8865 x86_64]#
[root@vps8865 x86_64]#
[root@vps8865 x86_64]#
[root@vps8865 x86_64]#
[root@vps8865 x86_64]# yum install libsmartcols
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: pkg.adfinis.com
 * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.net-d-sign.de
 * updates: mirror.23m.com
Package libsmartcols-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@vps8865 x86_64]# yum install libuuid
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.netzwerge.de
 * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.net-d-sign.de
 * updates: mirror.23m.com
Package libuuid-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@vps8865 x86_64]# yum install libmount
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: pkg.adfinis.com
 * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.net-d-sign.de
 * updates: mirror.23m.com
Package libmount-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@vps8865 x86_64]# yum install libblkid
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.netzwerge.de
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.net-d-sign.de
 * updates: mirror.23m.com
Package libblkid-2.23.2-65.el7_9.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@vps8865 x86_64]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package is `...2.32.2-65.el7.1...` and the installed packages are  `...2.32.2-65.el7_9.1...`. By the same version numbers, they probably come form the same source package, and presumably so should yours.

Perhaps you missed to update some version in the spec file, or your `dist` macro is off (i.e., it reads `el7.1` when it should be `el7_9.1`. In any case, at least the release (here 65) should be later than the upstream one, in order to avoid RPM database confusion (distribution package has the same version+release as the local, *different*, installed one is sure to make for entertaining fireworks later on).

Answer (score 0):

You either downloaded an older source rpm or have not applied the needed patches. Start with searching for a newer source rpm than the one you have.